# How to convert String variable in data frame to date in python

Tags: python, string, date, pandas, dataframe

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import date
clv['Date']=datetime.strptime(clv['Date'], "%m/%d/%Y").date()
```

Comment: Take a look to [`pd.to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Comment: What string do you want to convert in what dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`pd.to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html). After that you will convert your date string to Series of datetime64 dtype. Then you could access to date with [`dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html):

```
clv['Date']=pd.to_datetime(clv['Date'], format="%m/%d/%Y").dt.date
```